# Github api auth error redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: github, flask, oauth, uri

Github api auth error redirect_uri_mismatch

Hello, I've faced the problem with GIT OAuth Apps.
If I run the app on localhost, everything works fine. Git Auth setting for that case:
Homepage URL
`http://127.0.0.1:8080`
Authorization callback URL
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/github/authorized`

But if I try it on a real server, I get "authorization error: redirect_uri_mismatch description: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application."
Git Auth setting
Homepage URL
`https://random-number-alandreamfall.amvera.io:8080`
Authorization callback URL
`https://random-number-alandreamfall.amvera.io:8080/login/github/authorized`

The Flask code is:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    try:
        if not github.authorized:
            return redirect(url_for("github.login"))
        else:
            account_info = github.get("/user")
            if account_info.ok:
                return render_template('main.html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: ", e)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I've tried to add library from flask_cors import CORS, CORS(app)
add save session, change url_prefix, change Authorization callback URL from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: Do you set the redirect URI somewhere in the Flask app itself? When you get redirected to Github, do you see the `redirect_uri` value there? What is the value?

Comment: @Michal Trojanowski, I've tried this construction 

`github_blueprint = make_github_blueprint(client_id=client_id,
                                         client_secret=secret_key,
                                        redirect_url='https://random-number-alandreamfall.amvera.io:8080/login/github/authorized')
app.register_blueprint(github_blueprint, url_prefix="/login")`


A string with redirect_uri from a log file:

`redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Frandom-number-alandreamfall.amvera.io%2Flogin%2Fgithub%2Fauthorized&state=I146BRtTI0yJnF4tp8O5VHArdB2493`

Comment: The one from the log is different from the one from the configuration. You should now investigate why. In the log file, you have `http` version without the port number.